# Can I abstract away specific details about templated classes?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, factory, unique-ptr

I'm working on creating a factory library (similar to https://github.com/google/guice that is available for Java) in C++11 to familiarize myself with template programming, as well as create a useful dependency reduction tool. The idea being that the factory would abstract away the details of the creation and destruction of the object, and hide the implementation details. Ideally, I'd like to have something similar to:

```
InterfaceClass
{
    public:
    virtual void doSomething () = 0;
    virtual ~InterfaceClass () {};
}

// Might need custom deleter depending on how the class was allocated
// (might come from a pool, etc)
ImplementationClass : public InterfaceClass
{
    public:
    // Some (possibly) complicated constructor.
    ImplementationClass(Dependency one, Other dependency) {}

    virtual void doSomething ()
    {
        // Implementation
    }

    virtual ~ImplementationClass ()
    {

    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like the end user of the library to just be able to (or something similar):

```
std::unique_ptr<InterfaceClass> object = factory<InterfaceClass>();
```

This works great if all classes use the default deleter, but in the case of custom deleters, the type for the unique_ptr changes from:

```
std::unique_ptr<I>
```

to:

```
std::unique_ptr<I, deleter>
```

-- and as far as I can tell, these types aren't compatible.

Is there a way I can define some sort of higher level "unique pointer" that doesn't care about the deleter in it's type signature? Other possible workarounds to keep the API agnostic to the creation / deletion of the object?

Thanks!

Comment: What do your classes need a custom deleter for? In what way a virtual destructor is insufficient to customize cleanup?

Comment: One such use case I had in mind: when acquiring an object, it may come from a pool of pre-allocated memory. In that case, I wouldn't want to have the unique_ptr free that memory. The pool it was created with might want to keep a count of available blocks, and deletion in that case is just marking a block as available again.

Comment: Presumably, it's the factory that would know those fine details. So have it return the appropriate `unique_ptr` specialization; the caller could use `auto` to avoid having to spell out the type. Alternatively, use `shared_ptr` in place of `unique_ptr` - with `shared_ptr`, custom deleter is not part of the type.

Comment: Thanks for following through @igor -- I wanted to avoid using auto because that doesn't actually allow the two types to be compatible with one another. It just avoids having to type the differences. I also personally find that using auto makes the types of objects more difficult to track.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::function` to have a generic type-erased deleter.

[Ideone link](http://ideone.com/uVjZ3J)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
using TypeErasedUPtr = std::unique_ptr<T, std::function<void(T*)>>;

int main() 
{
    TypeErasedUPtr<int> p1{new int(5), [](int* x){ delete x; }};
    TypeErasedUPtr<int> p2{someAllocator<int>(5), [](int* x){ someDeallocator(x); }};

    // `p1` and `p2` have the same type, `TypeErasedUPtr<int>`.

    return 0;
}
```

---

This works because `std::unique_ptr<T, TDeleter>` takes any callable `TDeleter` type that can be called with a `T*` parameter.

An `std::function<void(T*)>` fulfills that requirements, and also polymorphically wraps any kind of function with that signature at run-time (by paying a small run-time overhead price).

Comment: Thanks! This worked exactly how I needed. The TypeErasedUPtr<> also was able to accept `std::unique_ptr<>` with no second template parameter as well (or rather, worked with both explicit and implicit parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can always wrap the type that needs a custom deleter. Actually you *should* do this, since custom deleters are implementation details which you wouldn't want exposed to the public anyway.